# a simple Guess letters game in java

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

i have just started writing a (guess letters game) as  an assignment .. in java (the first player  inputs 10 words and then 3 random characters will be hidden after that a second player will guess each character and  if he guessed correctly then a new word from the first player will be shown to guess the hidden characters until all 10 words are guessed correctly.. he has only 10 attempts  to get out of the program if he guessed incorrectly >>>>the problem was in replacing the hidden characters with the guessed ones from the second player

---

here how i hide 3 random characters form a string :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);


       Random r= new Random();
  String word= null;
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
                 word= s.nextLine();

    }
    int wordlength = word.length();
    int a=0, b=0,c=0;
    while(a==b||b==c||a==c){
    a= r.nextInt( wordlength);
     b= r.nextInt( wordlength);
    c= r.nextInt( wordlength);        
    }

    char[] wordsArray = word.toCharArray();
    wordsArray [a]='-';
            wordsArray [b]='-';
    wordsArray [c]='-';

    String modwords =new String (wordsArray);
    System.out.println(modwords );
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: the question is how to replace the hidden ones with the user input if it`s correct

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to break down what you need to do into smaller steps:

1. Get 10 words from player One
2. For each word, play a single round of the game using that word

Let's name these steps **getWords** and **playRound**

From the first step we want to get a list of 10 words: for this we can use a `List<String>`

So let's make a method for it:

```
private static List<String> getWords( int numberOfWords )
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++ )
    {
        words.add( s.nextLine() );
    }
    return words;
}
```

Now we can call this method to get our list of words, and feed them one word at a time to our second method:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int numberOfWords = 10;
    System.out.println( "Player 1: enter " + numberOfWords + " words" );

    List<String> words = getWords( numberOfWords )

    System.out.println( "Ready, player 2?" );

    for ( String word : words )
    {
        playRound( word );
    }
}
```

So now we have a simpler problem - playing a single round, which involves the following steps:

1. choose three positions where we want to mask out a letter
2. create a masked version of the word with the chosen letters dashed out, and display it to player Two
3. player Two guesses a letter:
4. is the guess correct? If so, replace the corresponding dash with that letter
5. repeat from step 3 until all dashes are gone

Let's name the first three steps as methods:

```
private static List<Integer> getMaskPositions( String word ) { ... }

private static StringBuilder createdMaskedWord( String word, List<Integer> maskPositions ) { ... }

private static char getNextGuess( ) { ... }
```

Then we can use these in our `playRound()` method:

```
private static void playRound( String word )
{
    // choose three positions to mask out:
    List<Integer> maskPositions = getMaskPositions( word );

    // mask our word by dashing out the three chosen positions:
    StringBuilder maskedWord = createdMaskedWord( word, maskPositions );

    System.out.println( "The next word is: " + maskedWord );

    while ( maskedWord.toString().contains( "-" ) )
    {
        // fetch a one-character guess from Player 2:
        char guess = getNextGuess();

        for ( Integer position : maskPositions )
        {
            if ( word.charAt( position ) == guess )
            {
                // guess is correct: replace the dash with the right letter
                maskedWord.setCharAt( position, guess );
            }
        }
        // now re-display the masked word (showing any correctly-guessed letters):
        System.out.println( maskedWord );
    }

    // no more dashes left: all missing letters correctly guessed:
    System.out.println( "Well Done!" );
}
```

That still leaves the three methods to implement: **getMaskPositions()**, **createdMaskedWord()** and **getNextGuess()**, but now these are much simpler problems for you to solve (and you can re-use some of the code you already wrote).

Note that we use a `StringBuilder` to store the maskedWord: this allows us to change letters (can't do that with `String` which is immutable).

You can also improve on my code by checking for valid inputs: for example each word must be no shorter than 3 letters.

I'll leave the rest up to you :)

Answer (score -1):

read the user input to `StringBuilder` and compare `a`,`b` and `c` positions, if the user input char is equal to the original word char than replace it, something like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "hello";
    StringBuilder obscureWord = new StringBuilder("h-l-o");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true){
        int pos = obscureWord.indexOf("-");
        if (pos == -1)
            break;

        System.out.println("guess the letter " + obscureWord + " : ");
        char c = s.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (c == word.charAt(pos)){
            obscureWord.replace(pos,pos+1, word.substring(pos,pos+1));
            System.out.println("correct guess! " + obscureWord);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("incorrect, try again");
        }
    }
}
```

of course you can replace the `while` with a `for loop` for limit tries

Comment: @Aloosha, modify the answer to a complete example, please specify your requirements in a clearer way...

Comment: look>>>  if the word(Hello) after hiding the characters  appear like (H-l--)  the user for example guesses the letter e >> i want to show the result like this (Hel--)

Comment: @Aloosha, ok now i understand... modify the answer

Comment: got it .. put here it should be an initialized word ....what if i want a user to put  words and an other user to guess ... sorry but i`m a beginner  ...

Comment: @Losha show me what you got so far... this is a way to solve your posted problem, you will need to insert it to your code, replace `word` with the functionality to get the first user input and `obscureWord` with your functionality of picking random letters and replace them with `-` like you did before